# Accuracy or precision issues with this code

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I'm experiencing issues with the code below (this working code solves the *Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff* (TOV) equations in general relativity, for the hydrostatic equilibrium of a spherical star).  Mathematica gives me a lot of `NDSolve::evcvmit` error messages about **precision** and **accuracy**, and I don't know how to fix the issue.  I've indicated the troublesome parts with a comment (* ISSUE HERE *):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* p is pressure inside a star (positive number), Rho is the energy density (positive number), gamma is the adiabatic index (gamma > 1), alpha is the central pressure relative to the central density (0 <= alpha <= 1) *)

Rho[p_, gamma_, alpha_] := (1 - alpha/(gamma - 1))Abs[p]^(1/gamma) + alpha Abs[p]/(gamma - 1)
TOV[p_, m_, r_, gamma_, alpha_] := - (m + 4Pi alpha p r^3)(Rho[p, gamma, alpha] + alpha p)/(r (r - 2alpha m))

(* Numerical resolution of the TOV equations: *)
solution[gamma_, alpha_] := NDSolve[{
    p'[r] == Piecewise[{{0, r <= 0}, {TOV[p[r], m[r], r, gamma, alpha], r > 0}}],
    m'[r] == Piecewise[{{0, r <= 0}, {Rho[p[r], gamma, alpha], r > 0}}] 4Pi r^2,
    p[0] == 1, (* central relative pressure *)
    m[0] == 0, (* central mass *)
    WhenEvent[(p[r] <= 0 || Rho[p[r], gamma, alpha] <= 0 || 2alpha m[r] >= r), "StopIntegration"] (* ISSUE HERE *)
    }, {p, m}, {r, 0, 100},
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> None}, (* ISSUE HERE *)
    MaxSteps -> Automatic, (* ISSUE HERE *)
    PrecisionGoal -> Infinity (* ISSUE HERE *)
]

(* The end of the curves:  Rmax is the maximal radius of the star, Mmax is its total mass: *)
Rmax[gamma_, alpha_] := (p/.solution[gamma, alpha])[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]
Mmax[gamma_, alpha_] := m[Rmax[gamma, alpha]]/.solution[gamma, alpha][[1]]

(* Plot of the pressure inside the star: *)
pressure[gamma_, alpha_] := Plot[
    Evaluate[p[r]/.solution[gamma, alpha]],
    {r, 0, Rmax[gamma, alpha]},
    PlotRange ->  {{0, Rmax[gamma, alpha]}, {0, 1}},
    Frame -> True
]

(* Plot of the energy density: *)
density[gamma_, alpha_] := Plot[
    Evaluate[Rho[p[r], gamma, alpha]/.solution[gamma, alpha]],
    {r,0, Rmax[gamma, alpha]},
    PlotRange -> {{0, Rmax[gamma, alpha]}, {0, 1}},
    Frame -> True
]

(* Plot for some specific values of gamma and alpha: *)
pressure[1.84, 0.82]
pressure[1.15, 0.65]
density[1.84, 0.82]
density[1.15, 0.65]
```

Plotting the solution with other arguments is working well most of the time.  But for some arguments, I get a lot of error messages.  I tried changing `"StiffnessSwitching"` to `BDF`, and `Automatic`, it doesn't seem to help much.  So what's wrong with my code?  How can I get a beautifull and smooth output for all values `1 < gamma <= 2` and `0 <= alpha <= 1`?

Also, the second output is weird!  The curve should end at 0, at the bottom right.  Apparently, the `WhenEvent` isn't working properly.  From the two differential equations to be solved, the `pressure` and the density `Rho` should both reach 0 at the same point.  The second graphics shows that the `pressure` is not 0 (near `r = 0.9`), while `Rho` is 0 (fourth output).  Since `1 < gamma <= 2` and `0 <= alpha <= 1` (positive numbers only), this shouldn't happen.  So what's wrong with the `WhenEvent` in that code?

Comment: On first glance, I see many symbols without definitions, so it'll be difficult to help you until you provide a working example.

Comment: @lericr, I added some comments to help the interpretation.  This working code solves the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff (TOV) equations in general relativity, for the hydrostatic equilibrium of a spherical cow.

Comment: At first glance, `pressure[]` and `density[]` call `NDSolve` a lot -- 11 times! -- because every call to `solution[]` calls `NDSolve` to compute the solution afresh. That's why you get a lot of errors instead of just one. If you change `WhenEvent[]` to simply `WhenEvent[p[r] <= 0, "StopIntegration"]`, the error goes away. The reason the second output is weird has nothing to do with `WhenEvent`, I think. `WhenEvent` stops the integration when `Rho[p[r]...] <= 0`, and `p[r]` is what it is (which is not zero). `Solve[Rho[p[r],1.15,0.65] == 0]` shows that there is a solution with `p[r]>0`.

Comment: Also, instead of connecting the events together with `Or[]`, you might want them to be separate events.  The connectedness seemed to cause the `FindRoot` error.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Now, the solutions that give `Rho = 0` and yet `p > 0` is really puzzling me.  If $\alpha > \gamma - 1$, then \begin{equation} p_0 = \Bigl( \frac{\alpha - (\gamma - 1)}{\alpha} \Bigr)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}} > 0\end{equation} gives $\rho = 0$ (so you're right that the pressure can stay non-zero at zero energy density!).  That was unexpected and it's probably non-physical.  I'll have to dig this!  Is there a way to prevent the numerical integration to select the solution with a non-zero pressure while `Rho = 0`?

Comment: `WhenEvent[Rho[p[r], gamma, alpha] <= 0 && p[r] < 10^-4, "StopIntegration"]` makes it skip the `p[r] > 0` solution (if it's bigger than 10^-4 -- I assumed, didn't test, that 10^-4 was small enough for all cases). Unfortunately, `Rho` becomes negative, which, if it represents a radius, is definitely non-physical. So no, I don't know a way to do it. I think the equations give you only those two choices.